# Are bound functions always Henstock-kurzweil integrable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, gauge-integral

Is there any function $f:[\alpha,\beta]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is bound but not  Henstock-kurzweil integrable? I assume such a function would have to be horrendously discontinuous but I am unable to construct one.

Edit: Perhaps we can defined a function on $[0,1]$ that equals $1$ on the Cantor set and $0$ otherwise. I might be wrong, but it seems like perhaps something like that would work.

Comment: What does "dense graph" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Notice Lebesgue and H-K integrals are equivalent for $f$ bounded with compact support.

Comment: I know virtually nothing about Lebesgue integrals, but I will keep this in mind when I study them. Thanks for the response.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340307/bounded-function-on-compact-interval-that-is-not-lebesgue-integrable